# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

My Model

```
public class ModelMessage {
    private String message;
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

My Interface

```
public interface Noqta {
    @GET("api/")
    Call<ModelMessage> message();
}
```

My Call on Activity click

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://noqta.tk/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Noqta noqta = retrofit.create(Noqta.class);
        Call<ModelMessage> call = noqta.message();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelMessage> call, Response<ModelMessage> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    tv.setText("True");
                }else{
                    tv.setText("False");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelMessage> call, Throwable t) {
                tv.setText("Error");
            }
        });
```

json body on noqta.tk/api

```
{"message":"Hello World from api web"}
```

What i am doing bad?
I have internet permission on manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines to your **build.gradle** in the android section:

```
android{
    compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

can someone explain to me why this is the solution?
I see that the error is in:

```
.baseUrl("http://noqta.tk/")
```

**Edit**

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - for me the issue was that I did set the baseUrl to be a specific path, Instead of setting it to be only the domain.

For instance instead of setting baseUrl to be:

```
.baseUrl("https://quotable.io/quotes")
```

You should set it to be:

```
.baseUrl("https://quotable.io")
```

Comment: That's strange, because [according to the docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#baseUrl-okhttp3.HttpUrl-) you can have path in `baseUrl`